# DotNet :- How to save username & password?

Tags: .net, desktop-application

I have a windows form application. there is a checkbox remember me. now i want if i check this box , then the username is saved in some file on local computer , so that it can be used after some time. also how to read that file so that the username & password are automatically set when the form is started again

Comment: Best practice: **NEVER** store a password

Comment: @ Marc_s :- then what should i do to achieve this.when a user opens the application it should have pre filled fields i.e. username & password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or another simple method is writing both in a text file. But don't forgot to encrypt the password.

You can decide to use the first line for username and the second line for password.

```
public void SaveUserPass(string username, string password)
{
  using (var credentialFile = new StreamWriter("credentials.txt", false))
  {
    credentialFile.WriteLine(username);
    credentialFile.WrtieLine(password); // Please save encrypted!
  }
}


public void ReadUserPass(out string username, out string password)
{
  using (var credentialFile = new StreamReader("credentials.txt", false))
  {
    var lines = credentialFile.ReadLine();
    username = lines[0];
    password = lines[1]; // don't forget to decrypt if you have encrypted before!
  }
}
```

Instead of using out parameters you can split the method for username and password or use properties of the same class or make your own class for the arguemtns. It's up to you. The code above is just a simple example!

Kind regards

Comment: Remind, this is just a simple example and not a best practice. I agree fully with the other participants - do not save password in that way, probably don't save password at all!

Comment: please tell me whether username = lines[0];   this will be directly read or it is in character form and we have to convert it into string

Comment: ReadLine() returns a string array. the number in the brackets us the array index. The .NET framework has a well written API documentation. May you have a look at it?!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know its good practice or not. But you can use Project -> Settings for this. So you can access the values as Properties. Make sure you are encrypting it ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you can use ISO - isolated storage to store password, here's quick tutorial on how to work with it [ISO](http://www.roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0194.html)

Another thing is that you should store encrypted password or a hash version of it but never keep password in pure form

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that a password should never be saved.

If you did want to store user settings related to an application, you can use Isolated Storage.

More Information: [When to use IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx)